# Can Qt manage smooth motion of objects using QGraphicScene and QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, animation, qgraphicsview

I am soon going to be writing a simple simulator for a robot. It will need to have only a 2D top-down view of the robot in its environment. The robot will be able to move around that environment and I want to show the motion as smoothly as possibe.

My first choice of framework is Qt. However, when I make a simple demonstration of a QGraphicsItem object moving around, the display is not as smooth as I would hope. Motion stutters - sometimes badly. There is no clear way to synchronise with the frame rate with vsync.

The update rate of the robot state is at about 500Hz as it is simulating a real-time system and there will be other inputs and events.

I have a minimal demo written with Qt5 and listed below.

- Am I approaching this problem in the wrong way?
- Can Qt5 give me the smooth motion display I want?
- Have I simply done something wrong?
- Should I look to another framework for this kind of thing?
- If so, what might be a better (cross-platform and free) alternative?

```
// main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    return app.exec();
}
```

The demo:

```
//mainwindow.h
#pragma once

#include <QBrush>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Blob : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Blob() {
    }

    QRectF boundingRect() const override {
        float adjust = 1.0;
        QRectF rect(-r, -r, 2 * r, 2 * r);
        rect.adjust(-adjust, -adjust, adjust, adjust);
        return rect;
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override {
        painter->save();
        painter->setPen(Qt::blue);
        painter->setBrush(Qt::green);
        painter->drawEllipse(QRectF(-r, -r, 2 * r, 2 * r));
        painter->restore();
    }

    float r = 40;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsView *view;
    Blob *blob;
    QTimer timer;

    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        setWindowTitle("Animation Demo");
        resize(400, 300);

        scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        scene->setSceneRect(-300, -300, 600, 600);

        view = new QGraphicsView(scene, this);
        view->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        view->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);

        QPushButton *btnStart = new QPushButton("Start", this);
        QPushButton *btnStop = new QPushButton("Stop", this);
        connect(btnStart, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::start);
        connect(btnStop, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::stop);

        QVBoxLayout *buttonLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
        buttonLayout->addWidget(btnStart);
        buttonLayout->addWidget(btnStop);
        buttonLayout->addStretch();

        QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
        mainLayout->addWidget(view);
        mainLayout->addLayout(buttonLayout);

        QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
        centralWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
        setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

        blob = new Blob();
        blob->setPos(0, 0);
        scene->addItem(blob);

        show();        // fitInView only works after the widow is shown
        view->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        QObject::connect (&timer, SIGNAL (timeout()), this, SLOT (animate()));
    }
public slots:
    void stop(){
        timer.stop();
    };
    void start() {
        timer.start(2);
    }
    void animate() {
        static float theta = 0;
        static float phi = 0;
        theta += M_PI / 1000;
        phi += M_PI / 470;
        float x = 200 * sin(theta);
        float y = 200 * sin(phi);
        blob->setPos(x, y);
    }
};
```

Comment: QGraphics stuff can never be very smooth. This is one of the motivations why Qt Quick 2 and its scene graph stuff was developed for Qt5 (Qt 4 QtQuick used QGraphicsScene). So, if you want it smooth, implement the view with Qt Quick. There are many ways, for example you could just slap your robot parts into a `QStandardItemModel` and use QML `Repeater` to make Qt Quick manage creation of the visual items for the parts based on model data.